Disable NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription iOS permission in react-native
I'm getting warnings from App Store Connect about a missing purpose string for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription but my react-native app doesn't use any location services. If I remove the string from my Info.plist file I get a warning about needing it to be set because my app references the location APIs.
My app isn't using any of the location services as far as I know. Is there a way to figure out what packages I'm using that are referencing the location services, and how to disable them?
This is with react-native 0.74.3.

Please provide package.json for check. another you can add detailed purpose of NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in info.plist .

I'm not asking which packages reference the location APIs, I'm asking how to find out if a package is referencing the location APIs.
Adding a detailed purpose does not make sense, since I'm not using the location APIs.
